# Does PHP Validate Requests Against a WSDL Prior to Sending the Request?

Tags: php, soap, error-handling, soap-client

I am working on integrating an existing software package with a third party software package utilizing a SOAP-based API. However, I am not able to generate the XML from the last request to help troubleshoot, because I don't believe the call to actually be made. The only logical explanation I can come up with is that PHP is validating the request against the WSDL before actually sending the request. The code is not necessary for this question, and I have tried too many variations for this to pick one or two samples to share. I have replaced the faulty SOAP call with a valid one, and the XML is generated and returned successfully and as expected.

Does anyone know how to determine if PHP is making the requests and the request is failing, or is it possible to have PHP invalidate the request against the WSDL and fail to make the call at all?

If you have questions, please feel free to ask. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging your script to see if it's actually making the request, PHP's [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) object makes it quite easy. Take a look at [SoapClient::_*getLastRequest*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php) and [SoapClient::_getLastResponse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php).

If you want something a little lower, [ngrep](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ngrep) is a nice simple tool for keeping an eye on what's going across the wire.

Take this simple PHP script...

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.27seconds.com/kb/ws/Articles.asmx?WSDL');
$article = $client->GetArticle(array('articleId' => 7));
```

Executing `ngrep port 80 &` and then executing the above script will dump the traffic, and it should look similar to this...

```
##
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [AS]
  ..                                                                                                                                                                  
##
T 10.0.2.15:40760 -> 208.106.153.223:80 [AP]
  POST /kb/ws/Articles.asmx HTTP/1.1..Host: www.27seconds.com..Connection: Keep-Alive..User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6..Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8..
  SOAPAction: "http://dsetzer.27seconds.com/ws/GetArticle"..Content-Length: 279....<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>.<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://sc
  hemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://dsetzer.27seconds.com/ws/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetArticle><ns1:articleId>7</ns1:articleId></ns1:GetArticle></SOA
  P-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>.                                                                                                                                    
#
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [A]
  ......                                                                                                                                                              
#
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [A]
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2013 21:11:21 GMT..Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0..X-Powered-By: ASP.NET..X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727..Cache-Control: private, max-age
  =0..Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8..Content-Length: 4804....<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/
  envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetArticleResponse xmlns="http://dsetzer.2
  7seconds.com/ws/"><GetArticleResult><xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msda
  ta"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element 
  name="Articles"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="ArticleID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="ArticleTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="
  0" /><xs:element name="ArticleSummary" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="ArticleAuthorID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="ArticlePu
  blishDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="AuthorName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="AuthorEmail" type="xs:string" minOccu
  rs="0" /><xs:element name="AuthorHomepage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="ArticleBody" t                                                        
##
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [AP]
  ype="xs:string" minOccurs="0                                                                                                                                        
##
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [A]
  " /><xs:element name="ArticleRating" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element><xs:element name="Authors"><xs:complexType><xs:seq
  uence><xs:element name="AuthorID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="AuthorName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="AuthorEmail" type="
  xs:string" minOccurs="0" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element><xs:element name="Applicables"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="appID" type="xs
  :int" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="appDescr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element><xs:element name="Keywords"><xs:compl
  exType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="KeyID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="KeyArticleId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="Keyword" 
  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="ur
  n:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><NewDataSet xmlns=""><Articles diffgr:id="Articles1" msdata:rowOrder="0
  "><ArticleID>7</ArticleID><ArticleTitle>Handle double quotes in a form.</ArticleTitle><ArticleSummary>When pulling data from a form or database you can into trouble
   if the data contains a double quote (&amp;quot;).</ArticleSummary><ArticleAuthorID>1</ArticleAuthorID><Arti                                                        
##
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [AP]
  clePublishDate>2002-03-05T11                                                                                                                                        
##
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [A]
  :40:54-05:00</ArticlePublishDate><AuthorName>Douglas L. Setzer, II</AuthorName><AuthorEmail>dsetzer@27seconds.com</AuthorEmail><AuthorHomepage>http://www.27seconds.
  com</AuthorHomepage><ArticleBody>&lt;p&gt;..When I was dynamically populating form values, I found that if the data has a double quote (&amp;qout;) in it, it would 
  cut off the data entered in the form...&lt;/p&gt;....&lt;p&gt;..To solve this, I found that I could simple Server.HtmlEncode the value and all was well.  Except whe
  n I was populating from a database and the data was NULL which caused an error for Server.HtmlEncode.  So, I whipped up this little function:..&lt;/p&gt;....&lt;p&g
  t;..&lt;div style="width=450;height=300;overflow=scroll;"&gt;..&lt;pre&gt;..Function formEncode(formValue)..Dim m_sOut..    m_sOut = formValue.....If IsNull(m_sOut)
   Then....m_sOut = ""...Else....m_sOut = Server.HTMLEncode(m_sOut)...End If.....formEncode = m_sOut....End Function..&lt;/pre&gt;..&lt;/div&gt;..&lt;/p&gt;....&lt;p&
  gt;This is used when you assign a value to the form field:&lt;/p&gt;....&lt;p&gt;..&lt;div style="width=450;height=300;overflow=scroll;"&gt;..&lt;pre&gt;..&amp;lt;i
  nput type="text" name="example" value="&amp;lt;%=formEncode("The ""test"" is good.") %&amp;gt;"&amp;gt;..&lt;/pre&gt;..&lt;/div&gt;..&lt;/p&gt;</ArticleBody></Artic
  les><Authors diffgr:id="Authors1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><AuthorID>1</AuthorID><AuthorName>Douglas L. Setzer, I                                                        
##
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [AP]
  I</AuthorName><AuthorEmail>d                                                                                                                                        
#
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [AP]
  setzer@27seconds.com</AuthorEmail></Authors><Applicables diffgr:id="Applicables1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><appID>1</appID><appDescr>Active Server Pages (ASP)</appDescr>
  </Applicables><Keywords diffgr:id="Keywords1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><KeyID>386</KeyID><KeyArticleId>7</KeyArticleId><Keyword>CHR(34)</Keyword></Keywords><Keywords dif
  fgr:id="Keywords2" msdata:rowOrder="1"><KeyID>388</KeyID><KeyArticleId>7</KeyArticleId><Keyword>DOUBLE QUOTE</Keyword></Keywords><Keywords diffgr:id="Keywords3" msd
  ata:rowOrder="2"><KeyID>387</KeyID><KeyArticleId>7</KeyArticleId><Keyword>QUOTE</Keyword></Keywords></NewDataSet></diffgr:diffgram></GetArticleResult></GetArticleRe
  sponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>                                                                                                                                 
#root@precise64:~# ##
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [A]
  ......                                                                                                                                                              
#
T 208.106.153.223:80 -> 10.0.2.15:40760 [AF]
  ......
```

Notice the SOAP calls? There are plenty of other ways to do this, but debugging should be your first port of call. :)

Good luck,

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your question is : You are trying to make a SOAP call though PHP on server side and you don't know if the call is made.

If you want to check whether or not the call was made , you may replace the SOAP object with a mock object of yours and within the mock object try to see f the call is made.